# Python: Is there any way this code can be written by defining one or more functions?

Tags: python, function, days

Okay so I am not exactly a rookie but a beginner in python, and I have been trying to create the following program by using functions, however, I don't really know how functions work and it just seems a little tough for the moment. Here is the question:

> The length of a month varies from 28 to 31 days. In this exercise you will create
> a program that reads the name of a month from the user as a string. Then your
> program should display the number of days in that month. Display “28 or 29 days”
> for February so that leap years are addressed.

And here is my simple solution:

```
name = input('What month is it? ')

thirty_days = ['April','June','September','November']
thirty_one_days = ['January','March','July','August','October','December']
feb = ['February']

if name in thirty_days:
    print('Number of days: 30')
elif name in thirty_one_days:
    print('Number of days: 31')
elif name in feb:
    print('Number of days: 28 or 29')
```

Any suggestions are appreciated :) Cheers!

Comment: May has of course been removed from the calendar. It knows what it did! (May have done?)

Comment: 2 notes on this code: a) it's very clean, concise, and clear/self-documenting, so cheers on that b) define a final `else` case in case a different entry is made (not probably necessary, but a good habit to get into)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, saw it after I posted lol.

Comment: @ShadowRanger who knows, that _May_ never come up in the test cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the code in a function that returns the length instead of printing it. Then call the function and print its result.

```
def month_length(name):
    thirty_days = ['April','June','September','November']
    thirty_one_days = ['January','March','July','August','October','December']
    feb = ['February']
    
    if name in thirty_days:
        return 30
    elif name in thirty_one_days:
        return 31
    elif name in feb:
        return '28 or 29'

name = input('What month is it?')
print('Number of days:', month_length(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage some date utils:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

def length(name):
    d = datetime.strptime(name, "%B")  # parse month by full name
    l = monthrange(datetime.now().year, d.month)[1]
    # may not be needed as you dynamically get the correct value for current year
    # if l == 28:
    #     return "28 or 29"
    return l

print('Number of days:', length(input()))
```

Some docs:

- [`calendar.monthrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
- [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange)